# Is a golang cross build for linux on macOS better than a native build?

Tags: go

I build the same golang project on Debian and on macOS. For both builds the target is Linux AMD64.

So when building on Linux (Debian) it is pretty simple:
`go build -o binary-linux-host .`

On macOS I need to define the additional environment:
`GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o binary-macos-host .`

The binaries have now a big difference:
When I check both files with `file` command:

- binary-linux-host: `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, Go BuildID=7bXizsTEcVUnWJNuLN5b/S47Io61HslPvR0IQKrN0/zJYia4H-FuEs7Uoxkm57/tsrcM-XCGbew3MEjFpVf, not stripped`
- binary-macos-host: `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=Rvqvk3lwWWhe37vMQQdm/qeLvo6Khm04nh3MPa5lH/0JfljUjzPbtqoLmKbcgw/XLOSnHOrCS5AJ7MRrWH8, not stripped`

Also when checking both binaries with `ldd`:

- binary-linux-host: has dependencies like libc
  `linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffffbba000) libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007feb7f875000) libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007feb7f6b5000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007feb7f8a0000)`
- binary-macos-host: `not a dynamic executable`

So I am wondering, why the build on macOS is static, but not the build on Linux?
Is it better to build the Linux target on macOS to have a binary that is more compatible to different Linux distributions?

Comment: Non-dynamically linked certainly sounds more like the go portable binary. You might want to add linux as tag (and perhaps kernel dev?) since your question is in depth on portability behaviour.

Can you add a 3rd build and comparison?
Build on linux with the explicitly set environment variables as what you used on Mac. That might show another difference

Comment: It’s static because you are not using cgo when cross compiling. If you have the toolchain to cross compile c code, then enable cgo during the build.

Comment: Also, if you want the static build on linux, just disable cgo.

Comment: @JimB Makes totally sense that cross compiling is static. And I will use the CGO_ENABLED=0 flag now for the compilation for all releases to have always a static binary. Thanks.